Hereditary property of bionto (bi-onto) functions
Let $\,\ X\,\ Y\ $ be topological spaces. Set $\ A\subseteq X\ $ is said to be clopen in $\ X\ $ iff both $\ A\ $ and $\ X\setminus A\ $ are open. Continuous function $\ f:X\to Y\ $ is said to be bionto iff for every clopen $\ A\subseteq X,\ $ and $\ B:=X\setminus A,\ $ either $\ f(A)=Y\ $ or $\ f(B)=Y.$
Open problem: Let continuous  $\ f:X\to Y\ $ be bionto. Let $\ A\subseteq X\ $ be clopen, and $\ B:=X\setminus A.\ $ Is $\ f|A:A\to Y\ $ or $\ f|B:B\to Y\ $ bionto?

The answer is no. Consider $X$ to be a disjoint union of four closed intervals (say, $X = I_1\cup I_2 \cup I_3\cup I_4 = [0, 1]\cup [2, 3]\cup [4,5]\cup [6, 7]$) and let $Y$ be a circle. The only clopen subsets of $X$ are the $16$ combinations of $I_k$ (each one we either take or don't take). Define $f$ on each of the segments to be an arc of angular length $2\pi - \frac{1}{100}$, so that the remaining arcs of angular length $\frac{1}{100}$ are pairwise disjoint. Then the union of any two of them covers $Y$. I claim that $f$ is bionto -- indeed, for any decomposition, in either $A$ or $X\backslash A$ we would have at least two intervals, and this part of the decomposition works.
On the other hand, if we put $A = I_1\cup I_2$, $B = I_3\cup I_4$ then $f$ restricted to both of them is not bionto -- just decompose $A$ into $I_1$ and $I_2$, and $B$ into $I_3$ and $I_4$ to get a contradiction.
